# How to find source of custom script execution?

Tags: shell

Once upon a time I created a script that cleans my "Downloads" directory. By the way, all it does is to move files from `~/Downloads` to `~/Downloads/Trash`. I store my shell script in `~/shell_scripts`.

I want to update the script, but sadly i realised I don't remember how I managed to execute it automatically :-( I started to search through Google on places to put execution of custom script, but in neither I found mentions of my script.

What I did so far was:

1. Checked `.bashrc` for both script name `clean_downloads.sh` and directory `shell_scripts`
2. Checked `.bash_logout`
3. `.bash_login` and `.bash_profile` files doesn't exist in my home directory
4. Checked `/etc/profile` for mentions and `/etc/profile.d` for copies of the script
5. Checked `/etc/init.d`

I haven't found copies of the script in any places except mentioned `!/shell_scripts` directory.  I suspect somehow I added an execution line to a system file, because I'm almost sure I did some kind of verification if I typed everything correctly.

Do you know any ways to find I kind of system logs if a particular script was executed and why (from which file)?

Comment: Have you checked  the `cron`  table (maybe also as `root`)? `/etc/rc.local`? Inside `/etc/init.d/` as a systemV init script? Is it maybe a `systemd` service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting cron is executing your script periodically. In that case the following commands might help you find the corresponding entry in cron's configuration:

```
crontab -e
cat /etc/crontab
ls /etc/cron*
```

Comment: Wow, you were right! Thank you, there it is:
`@reboot /home/asmox/shell_scripts/clean_downloads.sh`